# How to subclass custom Cell class with xib in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subclassing, tablecell

I got stuck with simple issue and can't find any solution.

`MyCell.xib` has fileowner `MyCell : UITableViewCell` class.

I use it like that:

viewDidLoad method:

```
 let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)
 self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myIdentifier")
```

tableView cellForRowAt method:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? MyCell
```

It works good.

I subclass my class to add some new methods:

```
 class SuperCell : MyCell {
      func coolMethod {
           print("cool")
      }
 }
```

And try to use it like that:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? SuperCell
```

it returns `nil`

How can I make it work?

I tried to create prototype cell in InterfaceBuilder with identifier `myIdentifier` and with class `SuperCell`, but it didn't help.

### Why do I need it

I just want to use the same view (xib) for different cell classes.

In my case I have common cell (`MyCell`) with view (xib). `MyCell` completely describes fields (IBOutlets). Also I want to create some another cell classes that subclasses `MyCell`, but they will provide some behaviour of these IBOutlets. For example `FirstMyCell : MyCell` will have method `setFieldsFrom(objectOne: ObjectOne)` and `SecondMyCell : MyCell` will have another method `setFieldsFrom(anotherObject: ObjectAnother)`.

Of course, I can just add this two methods into my `MyCell` class, but it will be unclean.

Comment: why whould you want to subclass a custom cell ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal please look my update

Comment: @JohnKakon did you find a way to subclass using same xib.

Comment: @JohnKakon Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @JohnKakon Did you resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

- Do not set the files owner (remove it)
- Make sure your your `XIB`s Custom Class is set to `SuperCell`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What If I will have `SuperClass : MyClass` and `SecondSuperClass : MyClass` with the same xib? Which one should I set in InterfaceBuilder? `MyClass`?

Comment: That does not make sense to me. Maybe update your question and describe your use case, what you want to achieve, more detailed.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no additional code required inside 'MyClass.swift' ?

Comment: Only code is `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier") as? SuperCell`. You certainly need to set outlets for Labels or such to `MyCellClass`.